# How to retrieve image into html table which its source stored in SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I have an ASP.NET project with C# code and a SQL Server 2012 database connected to it.

In the database I stored the source of image only; where the image is stored in project folder.

Now in my project I have HTML table in `profile.aspx` page. The table has one cell to show that image

How I can add the image inside the table and retrieve that image into the html table using its source that stored in SQL Server database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

Store your image link for example

```html
<img src=""....>
```

full thing inside a SQL Table column .
 While in your ASP.net Page include a

```html
<div id ="d1" runat="server">
  
  </div>
```

and while retrieving from SQL retrieve the same value and in your c# include

```
d1.text="retrieved column value that is <img src="...>"
```

Comment: Thanks dear **Abhi9255** i understod your idea